# Loop PHP / Explode

Tags: php, php-curl

Good evening,

I'm creating a script to check proxies.
But, I understand a little bit about the loop in PHP, I do my best ..

Here is the code:

```
<?php 

//$_POST INFORMATIONS
$address = $_POST['address'];

if (!empty($_POST['address']))
{

//COMPTE LE NOMBRE D'ENTREES
$delimiter = $address;
$delimiterArray = ($delimiter != '')?explode(",",$delimiter):NULL;
$arrayCount = count($delimiterArray);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $arrayCount; $i++) {

$url = 'http://api.proxyipchecker.com/pchk.php';

//DELIMITE L'IP ET PORT
$format = explode(":", $address);
$ip = $format[0];
$port = $format[1];

//CURL
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'ip='.$ip.'&port='.$port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

list($res_time, $speed, $country, $type) = explode(';', curl_exec($ch));

//REMPLACE LE RESULT
if (isset($type))
{
    if ($type >= 4 or $type <= 0)
    {
       $type = "Undefined";
    }
    elseif ($type = 1)
    {
       $type = "Transparent";
    }
    elseif ($type = 2)
    {
       $type = "Anonymous";
    }
    elseif ($type = 3)
    {
       $type = "High anonymous";
    }
}

//ECHO RESULT

echo $ip.":".$port." / Response time: ".$res_time." seconds / Country ".$country." / Type ".$type."\n";

 }
}
```

Error is here

```
//DELIMITE L'IP ET PORT
$format = explode(":", $address);
$ip = $format[0];
$port = $format[1];
```

Since it is a loop put [0], [1] it will be good for the first, and then it will be an offset ..
If anyone has an idea, thank you very much!

Informations:
Format -> IP:PORT,IP:PORT..

And I need IP & PORT for each address for cURL.

Thanks you!

Comment: This line: `$format = explode(":", $address);` should be `$format = explode(":", $delimiterArray[$i]);`. Also your `for` loop counter should probably start at `0`, not `1`

Comment: may i know what is the $address value example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking down what you're trying to do, your loop logic is a bit off and far too complicated for what (I think) you want.

...

```
//COMPTE LE NOMBRE D'ENTREES
//THIS IS THE FULL STRING (IP:PORT,IP:PORT,...)
$delimiter = $address;

//THIS IS AN ARRAY OF FORM 0 => "IP:PORT", 1 => "IP:PORT", etc. 
$delimiterArray = ($delimiter != '')?explode(",",$delimiter):NULL;

//ARRAYS ARE ITERABLE; USE FOREACH TO TRAVERSE EACH ENTRY

foreach ($delimiterArray as $value){
  $value = explode(":", $value);
  //THE COPY INSIDE OF VALUE IS NOW AN ARRAY;
  //$value[0] IS THE IP
  //$value[1] IS THE PORT
  //NOW DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH THOSE VALUES

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'ip='.$value[0].'&port='.$value[1]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

list($res_time, $speed, $country, $type) = explode(';', curl_exec($ch));

//REMPLACE LE RESULT
if (isset($type))
{
    if ($type >= 4 or $type <= 0)
    {
       $type = "Undefined";
    }
    elseif ($type = 1)
    {
       $type = "Transparent";
    }
    elseif ($type = 2)
    {
       $type = "Anonymous";
    }
    elseif ($type = 3)
    {
       $type = "High anonymous";
    }


}//end foreach
```

You will probably want to close each curl session after completion as well ([curl_close](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-close.php))